# What is the best calculation platform SQL or c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using SQL database for storage and my website is in c#, and both are on the same server.

I have inserted Students Result in a table in DataBase, which have fields like TestType, MAxMarks and MarksObtained.

Now i have to display complete result in one shot so i have to add maxmarks of all test types and marks obtained by students in those tests to display a final result.

My question is,

1) Should I fetch whole table from database and do all calculations in c# class?
or
2) I should do all calculations using t-SQL inside SQL server and then fetch the result?

Which of the above two scenarios is more server friendly? I do not want much load on server as database is huge with various simaltaneous login.

Which should be the ideal best practice in terms of load on server.?

Comment: Even on the same server, there's no benefit in throwing all that data between the two processes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it as part of the query. Let the database do the work in this case. If you have things indexed correctly it shouldn't be a problem. If you fetch the whole table then you're going to  run out of memory.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Should I fetch whole table from database and do all calculations in c# class? or 2) I should do 
>   all calculations using t-SQL inside SQL server and then fetch the result?

Ah - THAT DEPENDS.

How large is the tale compared to the results? if you have to pull 1 million rows to calculate 10, then this is not good. If you pull 100 rows and show them all anyway, the decision is differnt.

> Which of the above two scenarios is more server friendly?

Define server. More database server friendly, or more application server friendly?

> I do not want much load on server as database is huge with various simaltaneous login.

Define hugh and "various simultaneous login". Not ethat hugh is 1000gigabyte + these days and sql servers have no problems dealing with 10.000 parallel logins, so likely your server is tiny, and you ahve few users on it.

Seriously - it depends. SQL is generally a bad layer or COMPLEX calculations as it is hard to scale and expensive (licensing), but if the alternative is pulling a million rows down to do some simeple calcualtions thn - guess what, it is feasible. it requirs a lot more knowledge of basics than you provide, though.

Answer (score 1):

As the other people have already mentioned, everything depends on the specifics of your project.

Also remember that depending on the case (e.g. many reads but non-frequent changes) it can be worthwhile to precompute the report and store the results in the database. For example, I suppose the results of your student reports don't change more frequently than once a day. Run a batch job at night (or other hours that you know are less busy) that calculates all reports and store them in a database (maybe even a dedicated reporting database). That way fetching reports is dirt cheap and doesn't interfere with online transactions. You can even make report calculation smarter and have it only triggered when results actually change.

I also suggest doing complex calculations in C# instead of the database. It's more portable, more powerful and usually easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

As your calulation requirement is simple at the moment (just sum for maybe a year/student per test). You have the following options.

Solution #1

> Make a database `UDF(testName,studentName,year);` Inside this UDF you can run a switch or various if else statements which return
>   results by student names,year or all students,all years.

PROS:

- All result logic is emebed into the UDF. You don't have to calculate
  results again & again for any new form/requirement at presentation level.
  CONS:
- You have to monitor SQL performance when table size grows
- You cannot do much complicated calculations inside the UDF

Solution #2

> Make a utility class on presentation layer that sums up all results & delivers to your presentation layers.
>   PROS:
>    You can do complex calculations easily here.
>   CONS:
>    Might be a resource hog when result dataset is huge

Solution #3
Make a SQL trigger & a separate result table like

```
MaxMarks MarksObtained StudentId  Status    Year
-------------------------------------------------
500        100           1         Failed   2011
400       300            1         Passed   2010
```

You have to code the trigger in such way that it runs after every successfull row insert on your main table, these results will populate themselves. You can just query the result from this table on your requirement.

PROS:

- Not much work required
- Fast
  CONS:
  Hard to debug.
  You have to absolutely make sure the trigger works properly & does not messes up any record later